# Is a full pacifist run possible?

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

I've beaten the game today with no enemies killed and not detected bonuses on each level except the last two. It looks like no matter what I do, I indirectly kill a few stalkers in two sections:

In one section pulling a lever to open a door you need to progress also activates dart traps behind two stalkers overlooking said lever, killing them.

In another, stalkers seem to blunder into a spike trap even if I don't interact with the trap, or the stalkers themselves, in any way.

Did I get something wrong, does this make a complete pacifist run of the game impossible, or do I simply have to go out of my way to save those stalkers?

I forgot to take the screenshots of the sections I mean, unfortunately, but I can try to come back to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember the dart trap one, but I do remember the spike trap one: it's unavoidable, barring future patches to the stalker's AI.  Even if you distract her, eventually she'll return to her usual patrol path and commit suicide.

Whether or not full pacifist is possible depends on how you're counting it.  My memory is a bit hazy now, but it seems that the game either doesn't count stalker deaths, or doesn't count indirect deaths, so you'll still get the No Kills bonus.

Comment: This is closest to what I was looking for. While the game does not count trap kills, I intended to complete it without anyone at all dying, except for plot deaths, of course.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you define as full pacifist.

In those places, there will be deaths that you don't cause. It most likely can't be avoided. However, those deaths won't count in the end screen, against your score.

So it's possible to finish every level as a pacifist, from the game's "point of view". But it's not really possible to finish the game without anyone dying at all.

Comment: I meant exactly that - finishing the game without allowing any NPC die during gameplay, barring assassination targets and cutscene deaths, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I spared the two stalkers at the dart trap by

1) briefly stepping into the light so they get distracted
2) immediately jumping up and left to the wall
3) jump to the right, over their heads, as they approach
4) wait until they duck down into the grate to search for me
5) safely triggering the dart trap

It might work better with distraction tools. I wasn't using them by that point though.

Comment: Thanks. They can be distracted, and that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

THis is a slightly ambiguous question.

You cannot finish the game without killing someone. You HAVE to kill Karajan and Corporal Kelly (Obviously one of the endings always kills someone :P).

Even with this, it is absolutely possible to get the no-kills bonus on every mission. Karajan and Kelly are not included in this. I myself have complete this (not that there is an achievement to prove it >:( )

Answer (score -1):

I just don’t care about the stalker at the spike trap. She committed suicide, that’s her problem. HOWEVER my strategy for saving the stalkers at the dart trap room is: I pushed the light box to the left, went into the vent below them, planted a noisemaker where both of them could hear it and covered the ground with caltrops. Then I returned to the lever, set off the noisemaker, waited for them to check the vent and get foot pain and THEN pulled the door release, triggering the trap with no bloodshed. Easy. Well I mean blood came out of their feet but at least they survived.