# Can I complete the game both ways?

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

One of the many hailed accomplishments of the game was that you could go through however you liked, as a murderous savage ninja, or a sneaky rat never getting caught. I've completed it with almost no kills (a couple of accidents I couldn't be bothered to restart for, plus [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94810/is-a-full-pacifist-run-possible)) and I want to now run through murdering like a boss.

How? It seems like the only way is to select each level individually. Is this how it was intended or is there some other "mode" I'm missing to play through again.

It feels a little like cheating to play through the early levels with all the gear gained from final levels. But I don't really want to delete saves, I'd prefer to play with the existing data intact.

*Not platform dependant question, but I'm on PC*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game is designed for you to decide how you run through each level - there is no separate mode for being stealthy, or for killing everything you see. Short from clearing your save data, I'm unaware of any other way of removing the upgrades you have bought while running through the game the first time.

Comment: Well that sucks a little. So the only real objectives/awards in the game are those of points and objectives for each level, there's no overarching pacifist/rage machine awards?

Comment: I believe you get bonus points at the end of each mission for not killing anyone. Other than that, I don't think there are any overarching rewards.